# Run CTS 7.1_r7 suffered Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: cts

After run CTS 7.1_r7 on Windows10, device suffered Exception in the "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

> com/android/compatibility/common/util/IInvocationResult at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) at
>   com.android.tradefed.config.ConfigurationDef.getClassForObject(ConfigurationDef.java:308)
>   at
>   com.android.tradefed.config.ConfigurationDef.createObject(ConfigurationDef.java:282)
>   at
>   com.android.tradefed.config.ConfigurationDef.createConfiguration(ConfigurationDef.java:195)
>   at
>   com.android.tradefed.config.ConfigurationFactory.internalCreateConfigurationFromArgs(ConfigurationFactory.java:447)
>   at
>   com.android.tradefed.config.ConfigurationFactory.createConfigurationFromArgs(ConfigurationFactory.java:381)
>   at
>   com.android.tradefed.command.CommandScheduler.internalAddCommand(CommandScheduler.java:897)
>   at
>   com.android.tradefed.command.CommandScheduler.addCommand(CommandScheduler.java:891)
>   at
>   com.android.tradefed.command.CommandScheduler.addCommand(CommandScheduler.java:883)
>   at com.android.tradefed.command.Console$19.run(Console.java:606)Saved
>   log to
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\adefed_global_log_1730347923246130022.txt
>   at com.android.tradefed.command.Console$19.run(Console.java:589) at
>   com.android.tradefed.command.Console.executeCmdRunnable(Console.java:813)
>   at com.android.tradefed.command.Console.run(Console.java:908)08-17
>   09:47:10 I/CommandScheduler: All done at
>   com.android.compatibility.common.tradefed.command.CompatibilityConsole.run(CompatibilityConsole.java:77)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.android.compatibility.common.util.IInvocationResult at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

Update the cts.bat file solve the issues as linking the webpage as https://scottj.idv.tw/blog/2017/05/07/android-cts-v2-under-windows/